# Adding a list to the parameters file for Cloudformation template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, parameters, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template in which I send a JSON parameters file over. It was not a real problem, as my parameters file used to look like this:

```
[
    "InstanceType=t2.medium",
    "AmiStack=amilookup-stack"
]
```

However, I want to add a list to the parameters file, something like this:

```
[
    "InstanceType=t2.medium",
    "AmiStack=amilookup-stack",
    [
        "CertificateArn1=arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxx",
        "CertificateArn2=arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxy",
    ]
]
```

What is the best way to express this in my parameters json file, and how to express this in the cloudformation template itself?`enter code here`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1529) with Cloudformation. You can use [comma demlimited list](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) as parameter type.

Cloudformation Template (test.json)

```
 {
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "Name": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "SubnetGroup Name"
    },
    "Subnets": {
      "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Description": "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "myDBSubnetGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "description",
        "DBSubnetGroupName": {
          "Ref": "Name"
        },
        "SubnetIds": {
          "Ref": "Subnets"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Parameter.json

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Name",
    "ParameterValue": "testName"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Subnets",
    "ParameterValue": "subnet-abcdefg,subnet-abcdef1,subnet-abcdef2"
  }
]


aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name testStack --template-body file://test.json --parameters file://parameter.json --profile yourawsprofile
```

Comment: I added the certificates in the format you described to my original json file, but now I am getting the jq: error (at xxxxxx.json:21): split input and separator must be strings

Comment: Not sure whether I get your question. I think please include details to reproduce the issue